# tf.keras.Model.fit does not train the model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I stuck with strange problem with tf.keras. I can train a model with explicit training loop `sess.run([loss, train_op], feed_dict)`, but not with `.compile() .fit()` pipeline. It feels like gradients are not applied to the variables it this case. There is the simpliest code to reproduce the problem:

```
import tensorflow as tf
cifar10 = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = cifar10

image_shape = (32, 32, 3)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.layers.Flatten(input_shape=image_shape),
    tf.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.layers.Dense(10)
])
model.compile('adam', 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/5
50000/50000 [==============================] - 2s 44us/step - loss: 13.5849
Epoch 2/5
50000/50000 [==============================] - 2s 41us/step - loss: 13.5872
Epoch 3/5
50000/50000 [==============================] - 2s 41us/step - loss: 13.5871
Epoch 4/5
50000/50000 [==============================] - 2s 41us/step - loss: 13.5871
Epoch 5/5
50000/50000 [==============================] - 2s 41us/step - loss: 13.5871
```

Comment: I started with a bit more complicated convolutional architecture. Perceptron is here just for simlicity.

Comment: But is the poor training on the perceptron or the convolutional network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are performing classification, this means that the output should have a softmax activation function. Your model has no activation, so the values make no sense with the loss and this leads to a poor optimization process.

Change your model to:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.layers.Flatten(input_shape=image_shape),
    tf.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
```

And it should perform better, but also remember that this is a very simple model, it won't work well with CIFAR 10.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it should be some obvious mistake, just got used to PyTorch loss functions with built-in softmax.